# Issue 78326: AAPT prints sRGB profile warnings messages

Tags: android, android-studio, build, metadata, apk

Question:
I am getting this error when exporting my app from android studio:

> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
>   edited

A valid answer over the internet:

> It's metadata added by tools like Photoshop that isn't even honored by
>   Android. Strip it.
>
> brew install exiftool find . -path '*src/main/res/*' -name '*.png'
>    -exec exiftool -overwrite_original -all= {} \;
>
> provided by Jake Wharton

BUT

I have no idea what brew is and where to write this script.

Please let me know where to write the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a project that has these similar warnings and wanted to solve them.
As I understood it in this context Brew is a package manager for some Linux distribution and exiftool is a kind of image processor with console front-end which will strip meta data from images. In this case they are running it on files inside res folder with extension *.png.
Same (or equivalent) tool can be found for Windows here [http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/)
I am also pretty certain that you can do same thing using [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)
and could probably use any other tool and even Photoshop to strip this meta data from png files.
I personalty am using http://pnggauntlet.com/ for this but keep in mind that it does other optimizations to pngs also.

Also if you want the console approach here is a way to strip metadata from single image using exiftool on Windows

exiftool -all= C:\EXIF\dot_green.png

I am still looking into how to run it on the whole folder but will add that too if I find out.

Update:
This is probably not a best way to do it but it works:
put this into a bat file

for /f %%f in ('dir /b c:\EXIF') do exiftool -all= %%f

this will run exiftool on all images in the c:\EXIF folder.
Be sure to add exiftool to your path